# is ok to use both echo and return in function

Tags: php, function

I just want to know if is ok to use `echo` And `return` instead one function

The below code is one of my function

```
if(!function_exists("un_block_ad_ajax")) {

    function un_block_ad_ajax() {
        global $db;
        $is_admin = is_admin();
        $check_user = true;
        $request = $_POST["data"]["request"] ?? "";
        if(!in_array($request,["block","publish"])) {
            return false;
        }
        $ad_id = $_POST["data"]["ad_id"] ?? "";
        $ad_id = (int) $ad_id;
        if(empty($ad_id)) {
            return false;
        }

        if($is_admin === true) {
            $check_user = false;
        }

        if($check_user === true) {
            if(is_login() === false) {
                return false;
            }
            $get_ad_info = $db->select("SELECT ad_publisher FROM ads WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1",[$ad_id],["%i"]);
            $get_ad_info = $get_ad_info[0];
            if($get_ad_info["ad_publisher"] != is_login()->id) {
                // User-undesired activity
                return false;
            }
        }

        $update_status = $db->update("ads",["ad_status" => $request],["%s"],["id" => $ad_id],["%i"]);
        if($update_status) {
            echo json_encode(["success" => true]);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I call function from one file

```
$method = $_POST["method"] ?? : "";
if(!empty($method)) {
    $allowed_methods = array(
        "signup_ajax",
        "signin_ajax",
        "add_ad_ajax",
        "upload_ad_image",
        "send_message",
        "get_message",
        "get_cnv",
        "del_add_to_fav",
        "delete_ajax",
        "un_block_ad_ajax",
    );
    if(in_array($method,$allowed_methods)) {
        if(call_user_func($method) === false) {
            exit(http_response_code("400"));
        }
    }else{
        exit(http_response_code("404"));
    }
}else{
    exit(http_response_code("404"));
}
```

So as you see in code I need to use return and echo

Comment: You can if you want, sure.  It tightly couples the function to the UI though.  Seems like it would be cleaner to have classes/functions which perform an action and return a result (if applicable), and have UI code on the page which handles output.

Comment: Imagine if you ordered a hamburger at a fast food drive-thru and, instead of the guy at the second window handing you your order in a paper bag, one of the fry cooks burst through the wall like the Kool-Aid man and shoved the burger directly into your mouth. In both cases you ate a burger, but one case afforded you much more control over the manner in which that happened. That's the difference between `echo` and `return` in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can do as you may need, however, I advise you maintain a standard, as in:

Let's say you want to return true to an operation now, but tomorrow you need true and a wholesome set of data of, for example, what was updated.

You may want to build a generic response for your application, where you can use the same function (or logic) to read every response you may eventually get.

A response containing of:

```
{
 'success' => true,
 'message' => [...],
 'visibleToHumans' => true,
 'content' => [...]
}
```

You can have an UI that handles the response of your request, that can read the content based off success.

Extra:
I'd like to advise to look up PDOStatements, to secure your queries.

> http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

Comment: Thank you ! I use prepared statement is secure too